# how do i write an equation in standard form by completing the square for $x^2 -9y^2-4x-18y=14$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graphing-functions, conic-sections

I'm really having trouble with completeing squares i can solve for circles and ellipses but i can't seem to understand hyperbolas or parabolas, help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are having trouble with completing the square for your equation, let us rewrite your equation in the form:
$$
Ax^2+Bx+Cy^2+Dy=E.
$$
First, we complete the square to this term only: $Ax^2+Bx$. Take a look this following step:
$$Ax^2+Bx=A\left(x^2+\dfrac{B}{A}x\right)=A\left(x+\dfrac{B}{2A}\right)^2-A\left(\dfrac{B}{2A}\right)^2.\tag1$$
Similarly with completing the square to the term: $Cy^2+Dy$.
$$Cy^2+Dy=C\left(y^2+\dfrac{D}{C}y\right)=C\left(y+\dfrac{D}{2C}\right)^2-C\left(\dfrac{D}{2C}\right)^2.\tag2$$
To answer your question, we have $x^2-4x$ and $-9y^2-18y$. Using $(1)$, we obtain
$$
\begin{align}
x^2-4x&=1\left(x^2+\dfrac{(-4)}{(1)}x\right)\\
&=1\left(x+\dfrac{(-4)}{2(1)}\right)^2-1\left(\dfrac{(-4)}{2(1)}\right)^2\\
&=(x-2)^2-(-2)^2\\
&=\color{blue}{(x-2)^2-4}.\tag3
\end{align}
$$
Using $(2)$, we obtain
$$
\begin{align}
-9y^2-18y&=-9\left(y^2+\dfrac{(-18)}{(-9)}y\right)\\
&=-9\left(y+\dfrac{(-18)}{2(-9)}\right)^2-(-9)\left(\dfrac{(-18)}{2(-9)}\right)^2\\
&=-9(y+1)^2+9(1)^2\\
&=\color{red}{-9(y+1)^2+9}.\tag4
\end{align}
$$
Now, plug in $(3)$ and $(4)$ to your equation. Thus
$$
\begin{align}
x^2-9y^2-4x-18y&=14\\
\color{blue}{x^2-4x}\color{red}{-9y^2-18y}&=14\\
\color{blue}{(x-2)^2-4}+\color{red}{-9(y+1)^2+9}&=14\\
(x-2)^2-4-9(y+1)^2+9&=14\\
(x-2)^2-9(y+1)^2+5&=14\\
(x-2)^2-9(y+1)^2+5\color{green}{-5}&=14\color{green}{-5}\\
\Large\color{blue}{\boxed{(x-2)^2-9(y+1)^2=9}}
\end{align}
$$
To learn how to **complete the square** in an easy way, I encourage you (dorjan) to learn from this [site](http://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/completing-square.html).

$$\\$$

---

$$\large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2-2\cdot x\cdot2+2^2-9(y^2+2\cdot y\cdot1+1^2)=14+4-9$$

$$\iff(x-2)^2-\{3(y-1)\}^2=3^2$$

Comment: (I think) The question is about how to do this, not just doing it. Of course if one looks at your answer with enough curiosity and attention one gets the idea, but an explanation would be nice.